# Is it possible to keep more than one facebook accounts information stored for login in PHP application?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I know that having more than one facebook account is against the facebook's policy but Imagine a scenario where three people use a single computer to access social networks.

What I want is a way to store the login credentials of all three users and when they upload a photo or video, the application asks them from which account would they like to upload the photo/video and user selects his account and the PHP app uploads it to specific account.

I have created an app that allows us to see basic info, upload photo/video but unable to solve this Multiple facebook account login/ Switch accounts problem without logging out from existing account.

Just like you guys would have seen in gmail, we can add multiple accounts and then choose the account.

Comment: "having more than one facebook account is against the facebook's policy" if it violates the policy it will likely be not possible

Comment: No, you do not want to store FB login credentials - apps are not even allowed to ask users for those. You want to store the user access tokens.

Comment: I don't know the facebook api but I would assume, there are two cases ... either you're writing an app intended to be used on a mobile device, then you login as a user and would have to logout again, if you want to be a different user. if you're writing a service, where users log in with their fb account, the fb api would return a token you can use to tell the api which user is performing an action. however, just educated guesses here.

Comment: @Akshay - What I can think of is storing the ACCESS TOKEN & USERNAME for each logged in user in a COOKIE and reading it via PHP to prompt the user to select which account to use. Hope that would work for you problem

Comment: you cannot store the username. you cannot even access the username. what you want to store is the (app scoped) user id. and you do NOT need to store the access token, at least not for that case. you do NOT need to prompt the user to select his account, because he can just logout of facebook and let another user login. you do NOT need to deal with this on your own at all.
for security reasons, you should always let facebook deal with this, do not just store tokens and let users choose another account with another token.

Comment: i mean, why implement some account switching possibility in YOUR app, while there is an official version of it already: logout and login of facebook. why make it complicated?